# how start many process(own program) when process is singleton in C#

Tags: c#, process, singleton

i have loop and  in loop my program spawn new process and new process is singleton  so other process cant start

```
foreach (var i in files)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\\Telock\\Telock.exe", " -S" + i.ToString());

}
```

how start 2 after 1 finish and ...

Comment: and...? [.](http://www.berlitz.us/PPC/Learn-English/270/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=english-exact&utm_content=ad1&utm_campaign=PPC2010&gclid=COrr-pqp9aYCFQRvbAodaA2GEg)

Comment: What is your question? and what does this have to do with singletons?

Comment: first process spawn  and second can not cuz only one instance of this(telock) process can be run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you look up `Process` class in MSDN (after all, you ARE using it)? If you had done that, you would have found the `WaitForExit` method.

```
foreach (var filename in files)
{
    Process.Start("c:\\Telock\\Telock.exe", " -S" + filename.ToString()).WaitForExit();
}
```

Take for habit to use more descriptive variable names (`i` doesn't really say anything, especially not for a filename).